# apt/aptitude: predict which daemons are going to be restarted

Tags: apt, services, aptitude, init

I'm looking for a way to predict before upgrading, which daemons are going to get a restart. I have a few updates lined up that upgrade some core libraries and daemons and it makes sense to me that if - for instance - libpam-systemd is upgraded, that all daemons using PAM get a restart/reload.

So to be clear: I'm not looking for the packages that get updated - I'm looking for the services/daemons that get a restart or reload issued from post install tasks triggered by a given upgrade.

Comment: I don't know if there is a better way to do it, but having a look at the `postinst` script in the .deb file would be somewhere to start. For example Dropbox wants to restart nautilus.

Comment: You're a layer too far. When using apt-get or aptitude (preferred applications as per man page), I don't have .deb files, nor would I see them in a standard upgrade scenario (I'd have to split tasks into `apt-get upgrade -d`, manual inspection, and continue). So neither of these tools can tell me? `apt-get upgrade -s` shows nothing useful.

Comment: "(I'd have to split tasks into apt-get upgrade -d, manual inspection, and continue)" Yes, that's what I had in mind... As I said, I am not aware of a better way to do it. Another reference that goes in the same direction is the second comment to [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/254307/29595).

Comment: Hmm, that would be a usable work-around as long as this policy.d stays in fashion. I'll consider it, but it still would be nice to get a report on reloaded daemons, so it seems I'll have to code that myself.