# How to take control over update action?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, software-updater

I have message (motd - message of the day) that there's some updates for my server.

Now, if I don't want simply to *do what they told me* (apt-get update, apt-get upgrade) and to have some control over the further update, what exactly should I do?

By having some control I mean:

- to have exact list of packages to be downloaded and installed
- to have ability to exclude some of them if I want so

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/51124/hold-packages-back-from-updates-without-apt-pin or http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package?lq=1

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` will give you a list of packages to be upgraded, and then asks `Do you want to continue [Y/n]?`. Typing `n` will not install anything but you still got your list. See the linked questions on how to prevent specific packages from being upgraded.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as the duplicate of any of those questions. OP wants to select which packages to upgrade, rather than marking them on hold. Also, he's on a server, presumably without a GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use [aptitude [image: Install aptitude]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/aptitude). It features a small semi-GUI for the terminal, with a nice way of selecting the packages you'd like to install. Here's a short how-to.

1. Start Aptitude; note: provide no arguments.

   ```
   sudo aptitude
   ```

   [image]

   Optionally, press <kbd>U</kbd> to update the package list (same as `sudo apt-get update`).
2. By default no packages are selected for upgrade. You could expand the group of packages by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   - You'll need to press <kbd>+</kbd> to mark the package for installation (or upgrade in this case). You can select whole group by doing this while the group is selected.
   - Press <kbd>=</kbd> to mark it as the current situation (revert the selection above).
   - To uninstall a package, press <kbd>-</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>G</kbd> to go the the preview of the action about to take (notice this is in a new "tab"). In the example below I selected only the "Security Updates" - others are not upgraded.

   [image]
4. Press <kbd>G</kbd> again to perform the operation, or <kbd>Q</kbd> to close the preview tab.

Please note that this is different from marking the packages as "on hold", it's just selective upgrading.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, gertvdijk.